# Using ARRAYFORMULA to auto populate a column for rows that contain data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

The title just about says it all.

We have a spreadsheet that has a date in Column A and then in Column B it compares the value of Column A with today's date and spits out the number of weeks between the two values.

`=ArrayFormula((F1-A8:A)/7)`

*NOTE: F1 = TODAY()

This is fine except it starts spewing garbage at the end of the column when it runs out of data in Column A.

I tried adding an IF statement to check if the cell in Column A for any given row is blank but it seems to trigger it as FALSE if any Column A row has data in it (rather than the current row).

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A8:A), "", ArrayFormula((F1-A8:A)/7))
```

Anyone have any experience getting something like this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I guess wrapping it in another ARRAYFORMULA makes sense (not sure why I didn't think of it before posting)...

The function now looks like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A8:A), "", ArrayFormula((F1-A8:A)/7)))
```

... And seems to be working well.